# I working command on the Terminal does not work set as a shortcut

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, clipboard

I have a English-based keyboard but I use a pt-BR keymap. The position of the backslash is different and I don't have access to it. I tried to create a shortcut to copy it to my clipboard so I could use it.
I installed an application named `xsel` to manage my clipboard.
I created a text file in `/snap` called `contrabarra.txt`,
its only content is a single backslash.
If I use the command

```
xsel --clipboard < snap/contrabarra.txt
```

on my ubuntu terminal I can paste `\` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
Even though that commands works just fine, I can't make it work as a shortcut.

I set it to work whenever I press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.
The shortcut works if I use another command, the keys aren't the problem.

I think that the problem might be finding the text file, but I don't know whether the shortcut uses another referential (cd something) and thus it does not work as it does in the terminal.

A solution could be another way to use backslashes, another program to manage the clipboard that has a different use and thus provide a better way to deal with this problem I find myself in, or a correct form to use the shortcut function.

Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer instead of editing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I created a .py program that adds '\' to my clipboard and I run it with Shift + /.

Python3 program:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('\\')
```

It needs a version of python3 and the module pyperclip installed.

To install:

```
sudo apt install python3

sudo pip3 install pyperclip
```

Shortcut command:

```
python3 snap/contrabarra.py
```

*I named the .py file contrabarra and it is located in my snap directory, but you can name it whatever you want and put it wherever you see fit.